# Resetting USB device without root permissions

Tags: usb, non-root-user, android

I'm getting a strange behavior on an Android system when quickly plugging and unplugging usb devices from a usb hub. What happens is that after some quick plug/unplug of a device on the hub, I start getting:

```
<6>[18121.010764] usb 2-1: new low speed USB device number 8 using tegra-ehci
<3>[18121.253237] hub 2-0:1.0: cannot reset port 1 (err = -110)
<3>[18121.478006] hub 2-0:1.0: cannot reset port 1 (err = -110)
<3>[18121.702795] hub 2-0:1.0: cannot reset port 1 (err = -110)
<3>[18121.927899] hub 2-0:1.0: cannot reset port 1 (err = -110)
<3>[18122.153156] hub 2-0:1.0: cannot reset port 1 (err = -110)
<3>[18122.153272] hub 2-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 1.  Maybe the USB cable is bad?
<3>[18122.378371] hub 2-0:1.0: cannot reset port 1 (err = -110)
<3>[18122.603889] hub 2-0:1.0: cannot reset port 1 (err = -110)
```

After this, anything I plug into the hub does not work until the hub itself is unplugged/plugged again.

I've been able to fix this non-responsiveness by sending an ioctl with USBDEVFS_RESET. Unfortunately this requires root permissions, am I correct?

Is there any other possible way to fix this without requiring root permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been able to fix this non-responsiveness by sending an ioctl with USBDEVFS_RESET. Unfortunately this requires root permissions, am I correct?

Probably yes.

> Is there any other possible way to fix this without requiring root permissions?

Well, if you're already writing your own application to send the `ioctl`, you could just make it setuid root so it always runs with root permissions, regardless of who is executing it.